# Assigning variable based on line content

Tags: python, regex

I have the following file (example):

```
<b n="First">
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<b n="Second">
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<b n="Third">
<v n="1">Contents</v>
```

What I would like to do is print out the lines of the file, depending on what the `<b n>` values are. For example, if the value was `<b n="First">` each line would print out like so:

```
First: Contents
```

However, I am unsure of how to change the value every time it passes over another `<b n="value">` line.

The only thing I have tried which has pointed me in the right direction so far is using a regex expression to search for the value I want: `pattern = '<b n="(.*)">'`

I have also tried the following code;

```
for LINE in FILE:
    VALUE = re.findall(pattern, LINE)
    print("{}:   {}".format(VALUE, LINE))
```

And this prints out:

```
['First']: <b n="First">
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
['Second']: <b n="Second">
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
['Third']: <b n="Third">
[]: <v n="1">Contents</v>
```

But my desired output is more something like this;

```
First: Contents
First: Contents
First: Contents
First: Contents
Second: Contents
Second: Contents
Second: Contents
Second: Contents
Third: Contents
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this output?

Comment: Probably better to use a parser

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that. To confirm, i would like it to be 'First: Contents'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty near actually.

Here's an approach, close to yours:

- set the current title to `""`
- for each line, check whether the line contains a title, ie whether it begins with `<b`
- if it contains a title, update the current title
- else, get the content and print the title plus the content

The code will look like this:

```
title = ""
for line in file:
    match = re.match(r'<b n="([^"]*)">', line)
    if match is not None:
        title = match.group(1)
    else:
        match = re.search(r'>(\w*)</v>', line)
        if match is not None:
            content = match.group(1)
            print("{}: {}".format(title, content))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach only using regex:

```
<b n=\"(.*)\"|<.* n=\"(.*)\">(.*)?<.*$
```

[Test the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/m1IJ09/1)

But you have to put your text in one line:

```
import re

regex = r"<b n=\"(.*)\"|<.* n=\"(.*)\">(.*)?<.*"

test_str = ("""<b n="First">
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<b n="Second">
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<v n="1">Contents</v>
<b n="Third">
<v n="1">Contents</v>""")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)

for a, b, c in matches:        
    if a:
        name = a
    if c:
        print(name, ': ', c)
```